# IntelliJ debugger not hitting breakpoints in a Maven Java Google App Engine project (Eclipse works)

Tags: java, eclipse, google-app-engine, maven, intellij-idea

So I'm starting to pull my hair out here. IntelliJ just doesn't want to trigger breakpoints, whereas Eclipse works just fine. I never thought I'd say that sentence :|

Here's my example:

- Create a clean new GAE project from the classic example [Google Guestbook archetype](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/tools/maven#maven_app_engine_archetypes)

> mvn archetype:generate -Dappengine-version=1.9.15
>   -Dapplication-id=your-app-id -Dfilter=com.google.appengine.archetypes:guestbook-archetype

- Uncomment the suggested lines in the pom.xml to allow remote debugging

  ```
      <plugin>
          <groupId>com.google.appengine</groupId>
          <artifactId>appengine-maven-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>1.9.15</version>
          <configuration>
              <enableJarClasses>false</enableJarClasses>
              <!-- Comment in the below snippet to bind to all IPs instead of just localhost -->
              <!-- address>0.0.0.0</address>
              <port>8080</port -->
              <!-- Comment in the below snippet to enable local debugging with a remove debugger
              like those included with Eclipse or IntelliJ -->
              <jvmFlags>
                  <jvmFlag>-agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,address=8000,server=y,suspend=n</jvmFlag>
              </jvmFlags>
          </configuration>
      </plugin>
  ```
- Run the devserver goal (which compiles, tests and runs the GAE environment)

> mvn appengine:devserver

**(ECLIPSE: WORKING CASE)**

- Fire up Eclipse Juno and import the project as a Maven project.
- Create a "Remote Java Application" Debug configuration
  [image]
- Set a breakpoint, Debug the app using the Remote config and BAM, breakpoint hit and app stops. As expected.

**(INTELLIJ 14: *FAIL* CASE)**

- Fire up INTELLIJ and import the project as a Maven project
- Create a "Remote Java Application" Debug profile
  [image]
- Set a breakpoint, Debug the app using the Remote config and BAM, breakpoint **FAILS** to trigger.

Other than the different IDEs, there is no difference in the project setup. This tells me I must be doing something wrong in IntelliJ, but I honestly don't know what.

It just works in Eclipse and doesn't in IntelliJ. :|

Any ideas?

-- Shane

Comment: Are you setting the breakpoint, in both cases, *after* attaching?

Comment: Doesn't seem to make a difference :\

Comment: I have a similar problem and my question is here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30088083/intellij-debugger-does-not-stop-at-breakpoints

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this question is still active.

I think you may have had the same problem I had.[Intellij debugger does not stop at breakpoints](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30088083/intellij-debugger-does-not-stop-at-breakpoints)

Are you sure your server is exposing the 8000 port for debugger to listen when it started. You should provide those JVM parameters if it is not.

Answer (score 0):

I have managed to get it working as follows:

- Add JVM flags to Maven/Gradle as suggested by IntelliJ.
- Do not use remote (as suggested by GAE documentation). Instead, **debug** `appengineRun` Gradle task (similar for Maven).
- Once it is up and running, hit Run/Attach to a Local Process.

**BAM!** The debugger is attached, breakpoint hit and app suspended

Comment: I'm glad you got it working, but your answer isn't particularly helpful. Saying "Add JVM flags to Maven/Gradle as suggested by IntelliJ" begs the question "What did IntelliJ suggest?" I wish I could use this answer, but I need more info.

Answer (score 0):

it is old question for sure, but this is the answer:

make sure you have in the maven run config `-DforkCount=0 -DreuseForks=false`

source:
https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/206825095-Breakpoints-don-t-work-when-debugging-maven-project-